# How to get a component to show up in the list of draggable components (for parsys)?

Tags: aem

I'm trying to create a component that I can drag into a parsys component, but for some reason it doesn't show up in the list of available components (see images below).  I'm pretty new to AEM, so if I sound ignorant, I probably am (edits to this question are welcome).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first and the foremost requirement for your component to be draggable is to have either a `dialog` or `design_dialog`.

Second, it shouldn't be part of the component group `.hidden`. It is fine if it doesn't have a componentGroup property at all, you can find it under `NO GROUP DEFINED`.

Set the `allowedParents` property of type `String[]` to `*/parsys`.

And finally make sure that the `jcr:title` is different from the name of your component. They shouldn't be the same. For Eg: If the name of the component is `text` then the title should at least be `Text`.

I haven't worked in the touchUI, but for sidekick this holds good. So I guess it should work for your case too.

Comment: I've tried this (I had all the steps implemented already except the dialog), however it still does not show up in the list of available components.

Comment: Apparently, I also needed to specify a property on the component with `name = 'allowedParents', type = 'String[]', and value = '*/parsys'`

Comment: Oops. Since you didnt specify your dialog properties, i thought you added it by default.

Answer (score 1):

First: Make sure you have a dialog defined.

Second: Ensure that there is a componentGroup defined that doesn't start with a period.  ANY group name that starts with a period will hide the component.

Third: Make sure the component is enabled with design mode.

[AEM Mastery blog post about getting a component to show in the sidekick](http://www.aemmastery.com/2013/09/18/no-component-show-sidekick/)